# Is there any alternative for django-markdown package?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to store markdown data in django model. 
I am using django==1.11
Currently I am using django-markdown package which has no updates from last 4 years.
Can you suggest a well maintained module which will provide a markdown field with validation?

Comment: You want to store it as HTML? Or as markdown? Who's going to edit your text? People that know what they are doing or any user? Maybe clarify your use case and what you're trying to achieve to get better advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [markdownx](https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx) and it does a good job for me. I use it with [django-markdown2](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-markdown2) to display it. In models.py its an easy as:

```
from django.db import models
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    text = MarkdownxField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And it also allows you to view markdown in the admin with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin
from .models import Post
# Register your models here.
class PostAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'date_created']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```